# how >=3 AZs guaranteed in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, region

Amazon S3 gaurantees that the data being uploaded to bucket will be spread across >= 3 AZs.[scroll down for chart](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/). When we create bucket, we enter region. How amazon manages this AZs number when we create bucket in the region where we have only two AZs?

Answer (score 2):

here's the answer from AWS S3 FAQ. Apparently, in those cases, more AZs exist, but they are not publicly available:

Q:  What is an AWS Availability Zone (AZ)?

An AWS Availability Zone is an isolated location within an AWS Region. Within each AWS Region, S3 operates in a minimum of three AZs, each separated by miles to protect against local events like fires, floods, etc.

Amazon S3 Standard, S3 Standard-Infrequent Access, and S3 Glacier storage classes replicate data across a minimum of three AZs to protect against the loss of one entire AZ. This remains true in Regions where fewer than three AZs are publicly available. Objects stored in these storage classes are available for access from all of the AZs in an AWS Region.

The Amazon S3 One Zone-IA storage class replicates data within a single AZ. Data stored in this storage class is susceptible to loss in an AZ destruction event.

Comment: Does it mean, If I create bucket in region having 2 AZs. Still S3 has one hidden AZ within same region which guarantees >=3 condition?

Comment: Yes, exactly. 2 AZs are publicly available, but they have one more used by S3

Comment: DynamoDB similarly uses a private 3rd AZ in regions that have only 2 public AZs.